# LINQ - Create a nested group in vb

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm trying to create nested groups in a visual basic LINQ query expression as shown here in C#: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/create-a-nested-group:

```
    var queryNestedGroups =
    from student in students
    group student by student.Year into newGroup1
    from newGroup2 in
        (from student in newGroup1
         group student by student.LastName)
    group newGroup2 by newGroup1.Key;
```

This is what I have so far:

```
    Dim students As New List(Of Student)
    '...getting students content ommitted here...
    Dim queryNestedGroups As IEnumerable(Of IGrouping(Of Integer, IGrouping(Of String, Student))) =
            From student In students
            Group student By student.Year Into newGroup1 = Group
            From newGroup2 In (From student In newGroup1 Group student By student.LastName Into Group)
            Group newGroup2 By newGroup1.Key Into Group
'                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ compiler red lines here

    Dim grouping As IGrouping(Of Integer, IGrouping(Of String, Student))
    For Each grouping In queryNestedGroups
        Console.WriteLine($"DataClass.Student Level = {grouping.Key}")
        Dim grouping2 As IGrouping(Of String, Student)
        For Each grouping2 In grouping
            Console.WriteLine((ChrW(9) & "Names that begin with: " & grouping2.Key))
            Dim student As Student
            For Each student In grouping2
                Console.WriteLine((ChrW(9) & ChrW(9) & student.LastName & " " & student.FirstName))
            Next
        Next
    Next
```

But the compiler is complaining about the **newGroup1.Key**:

```
"Key" is not a member of "IEnumerable(Of Student)"
```

What is the Visual Basic equivalent of the C# code?

Comment: `newGroup1.Key` is a Range Variable, here. It comes from an Enumerator. You need to use the direct reference: `Year`, as specified in `Group student By student.Year`.

Comment: You should probably add: `Order By student.Year` after `From student In students`

Comment: Ahm, the stupid tablet deleted a piece of the first comment. Before *You need to* there was: `newGroup1` is an `Enumerable(Of student)` at this point, it has no `Key`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jimi, this produces the same result as the C# code:

```
    Dim queryNestedGroups =
            From student In students
            Group student By student.Year Into newGroup1 = Group
            From newGroup2 In (From student In newGroup1 Group student By LastName = student.LastName Into Group)
            Group newGroup2 By Year Into Group

    For Each grouping In queryNestedGroups
        Console.WriteLine($"DataClass.Student Level = {grouping.Year}")
        For Each grouping2 In grouping.Group
            Console.WriteLine((ChrW(9) & "Names that begin with: " & grouping2.LastName))
            Dim student As Student
            For Each student In grouping2.Group
                Console.WriteLine((ChrW(9) & ChrW(9) & student.LastName & " " & student.FirstName))
            Next
        Next
    Next
```

As a drawback the result **queryNestedGroups** is now an anonymous type and no

```
IEnumerable(Of IGrouping(Of Integer, IGrouping(Of String, Student)))
```

but at least it works!

Comment: The result would be `IEnumerable(Of IGrouping(Of [Enum], IGrouping(Of String, Student)))`. You can make the the anonymous type re-appear as a Grouping with: `Dim StudentGrouping = [Students].GroupBy(Function(student) student.Year).GroupBy(Function(group) group.Key).ToList()`

Comment: No, that's just a  `List(Of IGrouping(Of GradeLevel, IGrouping(Of GradeLevel, Student)))` - the `String` is missing...